# How to set axios header dynamically according to access_token expired and url

Tags: javascript, axios

I am new to using Axios configuration. `**So I am wondering if it is possible to set axios header dynamically?**`

Because the end points I am calling right now need a Authentication and different authentication for different api, so I want make a change to the created axios instance’s header when token is expired and with different URL.

Here is my current code:

in config.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

// to get Authorization for api_1
const {access_token_1} = axios.get('url/access_token_1')
// to get Authorization for api_2
const {access_token_2} = axios.get('url/access_token_2')

export const instance = axios.create({
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token_1}` },
})
```

My Api_1 and 2 call

```
//Api_1
export const getCountry = async (country: string) => {
  const response = await instance.get(
    `/sas/${country}`
  )
  return response.data
}


//Api_2
export const getCity = async (city: string) => {
  const response = await instance.get(
    `/sps/${city}`
  )
  return response.data
}
```

I know header can be set again by certain method, but how could I set it again only when it’s expired and set the instance with right authentication for certain Api

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios), you can create/update headers and pass them to your axios instance. I think this examples might help a little

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';

// Important: If axios is used with multiple domains, the AUTH_TOKEN will be sent to all of them.
// See below for an example using Custom instance defaults instead.
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url,
};
axios(options);
```

```js
axios.get('https://example.com/getSomething', {
 headers: {
   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token //the token is a variable which holds the token
 }
})
```